# which codeginiter template systems best?

Tags: codeigniter, templates

I just want to make sure about this matter before starting my new project. So what templates system you prefer for codeigniter framework?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this one: Phil Sturgeon's template library, it's very `smarty` like and that's good.
link:

[code here](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/code)

[link 2](http://getsparks.org/packages/template/show)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use this library:

### [CodeIgniter Template](https://github.com/jrmadsen67/williamsconcepts-template/reference.html)

It is very easy to config and also you can extend it to. I use it a lot, and I like it very much.

Answer (score 0):

As Devil's Advocate, why don't use directly PHP in your templates? I use it, with the alternative sintaxis and works perfectly:

```
<? if ( $pepe == 1 ) : ?>
HTML CODE <?=$var1?> more template <?=$var2?>
<? endif; ?>

<? foreach ($key => $value ) : ?>
Key is <?=$key?> and Value is <?=$value?> 
<? endforeach; ?>
```

What are the advantages you're looking for when using a template system? With this, you don't load anything, no more syntax learning, and everything works smooth and fast.

Comment: My main goal is to be very very simple to work with. Sorry guys but I can't up vote you as I don't have 15 points yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Stencil. All logic for the layouts are done from the controller, but it makes development quick and easy. It's pretty well documented as well. Some of its features are:

- Easily set titles
- Simple Layouts Page-specific assets (js, meta, and css, perfect for jQuery plugins)
- Page-specific meta data Tons of HTML5 helpers
- Flexible ways of binding data to views
- Slices (also called partials, includes, nested views, elements, etc)
- Slice Callbacks (also called view models where you can execute a block of code
  every-time a Slice is used)

[Github](https://github.com/scotch-io/stencil)

[Docs](http://scotch.io/docs/stencil)

Full-disclosure: This is something I built.

Lastly, this question is asked [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3957000/what-codeigniter-template-library-is-best) and [over](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17571512/codeigniter-template-libraries-with-partial-views-which-one/17575450#17575450) again, and it should probably be flagged for a duplicate question.